# Search Google through speech recognition

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, web-search

The following code returns an empty search query and I need to use "search" as the activation key word and then search for the following word "search".

```
private static void rec_speachRecogmized(object sender, 
    SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
     if (r.StartsWith("search"))
         { 


     var spec = r.Replace("search", " "); 
        spec.Trim(); spec.Replace(" ", "+"); 
        speech.Speak("searching" + spec); 
        Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search? source=hp&q=" + 
        spec);
        }
         }
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please provide bug report and minimal code to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search? source=hp&q=" + spec);
```

In:

```
Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + spec);
```

Comment: i thought the problem is getting a speech after say search

Comment: what speech recognizer do you use? I tested with Microsoft's API

Comment: using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

Comment: rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
                rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_speachRecogmized;
                rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);